# Como fazer select comparando duas colunas

Tags: sql-server

Considerando a seguinte estrutura:

```
   Coluna_A   | Coluna_B |
01 João       | Carro    | 
02 João       | Moto     |
03 Maria      | Moto     |
04 José       | Carro    |
05 Maria      | Moto     |
```

Gostaria de realizar um `select` que me traga a informação, de acordo com a `Coluna_A` e `Coluna_B`. O resultado deverá exibir apenas as linhas cujo `Coluna_A` tenha mais de um valor, considerando que na `Coluna_B` tenha um único valor, ou seja, neste exemplo acima, a consulta deverá exibir apenas as linhas 01 e 02, pois João é o único que tem um carro e uma moto. Não poderá exibir a Maria que possui duas motos e nem José que possui apenas um carro

Tentei fazer na seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE ##TBL_TEMP(
    COLUNA_A VARCHAR(30),
    COLUNA_B VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO ##TBL_TEMP VALUES ('João','Carro')
INSERT INTO ##TBL_TEMP VALUES ('João','Moto')
INSERT INTO ##TBL_TEMP VALUES ('Maria','Moto')
INSERT INTO ##TBL_TEMP VALUES ('José','Carro')
INSERT INTO ##TBL_TEMP VALUES ('Maria','Moto')

SELECT * FROM ##TBL_TEMP
GROUP BY COLUNA_A, COLUNA_B
HAVING NOT COUNT(COLUNA_A) >= 2 AND COUNT(COLUNA_B) = 1
```

O resultado obtido é:

```
    COLUNA_A  | COLUNA_B
01  João      | Carro
02  José      | Carro
03  João      | Moto
```

Não sei por qual motivo está exibindo o José, pois não atende os requisitos do `Having`

Comment: Você tá agrupando pelas duas colunas, `Maria` funciona porque os dois dados são iguais.

Comment: se eu não agrupar pelas duas colunas da erro

Answer (score 2):

Penso que a solução passará por algo deste género:

```
SELECT      X.COLUNA_A
        ,   TMP.COLUNA_B
FROM        ##TBL_TEMP  TMP
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      COLUNA_A
                        ,   COUNT(DISTINCT(COLUNA_B)) AS CONTADOR
                FROM        ##TBL_TEMP
                GROUP BY    COLUNA_A
                HAVING      COUNT(DISTINCT(COLUNA_B)) >= 2
            )           X   ON X.COLUNA_A = TMP.COLUNA_A
```